# Numba vectorize for function with no input

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numba

I want to parallelize a function using `numba.vectorize`, but my function doesn't take any input. Currently, I use a dummy array and dummy input for my function that is never used.

Is there a more elegant/fast way (possibly without using `numba.vectorize`)?

Code example (not my actual code, only for demonstration how I discard input):

```
import numpy as np
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize(["int32(int32)"], nopython=True)
def particle_path(discard_me):
    x = 0
    for _ in range(10):
        x += np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    return np.int32(x)

arr = particle_path(np.empty(1024, dtype=np.int32))
print(arr)
```

Comment: So you expect an `arr` with (1024) shape?

Comment: Yes, I do. In principle, particle_path might be a Monte-Carlo simulation that should run for an arbitrary number of samples. Here, I call it 1024 times and get 1024 results of the simulation (of course, the simulation is omitted in the example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll simply be dealing with 1D arrays, then you can use the following, where the array must be instantiated outside the function. There doesn't seem to be any reason to use `vectorize` here, you can achieve the goal simply with `jit` although you do have to explicitly write the loop over the array elements using this. If your array will always be 1D, then you can use:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def particle_path(out):
    for i in range(len(out)):
        x = 0
        for _ in range(10):
            x += np.random.uniform(0, 1)
        out[i] = x

arr = np.empty(1024, dtype=np.int32)
particle_path(arr)
```

You can similarly deal with any-dimensional arrays using the [`flat`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html#the-flat-object) attribute (and make sure to use `.size` to get total number of elements in the array):

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def particle_path(out):
    for i in range(out.size):
        x = 0
        for _ in range(10):
            x += np.random.uniform(0, 1)
        out.flat[i] = x

arr = np.empty(1024, dtype=np.int32)
particle_path(arr)
```

and finally you can create your array inside your function if you need a new array each time you run the function (use the above instead if you'll be calling the function repeatedly and want to overwrite the same array, hence saving the time to re-allocate the same array over and over again).

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def particle_path(num):
    out = np.empty(shape=num, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(num):
        x = 0
        for _ in range(10):
            x += np.random.uniform(0, 1)
        out[i] = x
    return out

arr = particle_path(1024)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this was just the decorator I was looking for, but somehow ignored before. Furthermore, through your answer I discovered that the outer range can be replaced by 'numba.prange', which can be coupled with the 'parallel=True' option for @jit to gain a nice speedup on top

Comment: I apologize for missing that you wanted parallelization. Note that the abilities of `prange` (used with `parallel=True`) are limited; certainly try it out and see if it works. But if that doesn't work, use `nogil=True` in the decorator (to ensure Python GIL is released by the Numba-decorated code) and use Python's multi-threading capabilities (`threading` or `futures` built-in modules; also `dask.delayed`, etc.) to parallelize your code.

Comment: No worries, I didn't specify my need for parallelization in the question. It's just that my problem is embarrassingly parallel and I was happy to exploit it for free. The `nogil=True` and `threading` combination will then actually utilize multiple CPU cores (similar to `multithreading`)? That would be amazing

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If code releases the GIL (as Numba code does if you specify `nogil=True`), then even using the lighter-weight `threading` module, the various threads will execute on multiple CPU cores. Code that does not release the GIL needs e.g. the heavier-weight `multiprocessing` module in order to execute on multiple CPU cores.